# MVC Post (One Form Ajax) but fill three partial views with different controller requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an Parent View which contains 3 partial views, each inside of their own div.  What I am attempting to do is based on a form (single form) at the top of the Parent View, change out contents within each div (Partial view).  This form contains a simple dropdownlist (cCats).

Is the best solution to use JavaScript and post to each form within one function?  Or is there a way to do this within Razor?

Secondly, I am not certain how to do it either way.  Could someone show me a quick example?

```
@model App.Models.CategoryModel

@{
    int icatid = ViewBag.CatID;
    List<Categories> cats = ViewBag.Cats;
    var lstcats = new SelectList(cats, "CatID", "CatName");
}

@Html.DropDownList("cCats", model)

<div id="dfirst">
     @Html.Partial("searchlist",Model.CatID)
</div>

<div id="dsecond">
     @Html.Partial("employees",Model.CatID)
</div>

<div id="dthird">
     @Html.Partial("results",Model.CatID)
</div>
```

Comment: Does the use have to fill out all three sections of the form?

Comment: If the DropDownList changes, it would impact and alter all three divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Much Easier

You can use razor. Use an `@Ajax.ActionLink` or `@Ajax.BeginForm` HTML Helper.

They look like this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Check Available Rooms","AvailableMeals",
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "GET",
            UpdateTargetId = "Meals",
            OnSuccess = "" // display the user's selected form 

        } )
```

Comment: Thank you stink!  This looks exactly like what I should be doing.